# Align glyphicons icon to right and inside text input box

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I am trying to add a glyphicon-info-sign icon to a password input box created using bootstrap css. I am trying to make icon appear inside the password textbox and on the right side. I tried various combinations but icon appears at the bottom of input box.
Here is jsfiddle sample https://jsfiddle.net/bsbef0qd/ . Thank you.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group add-on col-xs-4">
    <label for="password" class="control-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="userFormPassword" id="userFormPassword" value="" class="form-control input-sm" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <a class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Some password instructions"> 
        <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></i>
      </a>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
    <label for="confirm" class="control-label">Confirm Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="confirm" value="" class="form-control input-sm" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/BG101/bsbef0qd/1/)

You need to use an `input-group` and take the `label` outside.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <label for="password" class="control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="input-group add-on">
      <input type="password" name="userFormPassword" id="userFormPassword" value="" class="form-control input-sm" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
      <a class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Some password instructions"> 
        <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></i>
      </a>
    </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) That was it